# Are multiple DAOs with jdbctemplate constructor injection a multi-threading risk?

Tags: multithreading, singleton, datasource, dao, jdbctemplate

I've got a large multi-threaded webapp in which I am passing in jdbcTemplates into DAO classes via constructor injection. Is this a multi-threading risk? Should I be passing in just the datasource instead?

Answer (score 1):

Spring IOC runs in only 1 thread on start up so threading issues are not an issue there.  Spring will not publish the DAO as a bean (to be retrieved from elsewhere) until it is completely constructed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no risk of multithreading, you can safely pass jdbcTemplate into DAO classes.
In every query execution method, it essentially talks to the injected datasource and **does not** use any state which could lead to any side effect.